# Performance impact due to Join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables PRODUCT and  ACCOUNT.

PRODUCT  table columns

```
product_id   (PK)                      
subscription_id
```

ACCOUNT table  columns

```
account_nbr
subscription_id  
  (account_nbr and subscription_id are primary key columns in account table)
... Other columns
```

I have to find `account_nbr` and `subscription_id` for a `product_id`.

I get `product_id` as input. Using it I can get the `subscription_id from PRODUCT table` and 
using `subscription_id` I can get the `account_nbr` value from ACCOUNT table.

Instead of getting the info in two queries, can it be done in one query?

Something like the below:

```
select distinct a.acct_nbr,p.subscription_id 
from ACCOUNT  a,PRODUCT p
where v.product_id = ' val 1' and 
v.subscription_id  = p.subscription_id
```

Will the performance of the above query be low compared to two separate queries?

Comment: Please, provide information about your DBMS - otherwise only common suggestions in terms of performance could be done since each DBMS has it's own issues when optimizing queries.

Comment: The database is oracle 11g.

Comment: Can you show the `EXPLAIN PLAN`?

Answer (score 3):

> I have to find account_nbr and subscription_id for a product_id.

So, you're correct in your approach you need to JOIN the two result-sets together:

```
select p.account_nbr, p.subscription_id
  from account a
  join product p
    on a.subscription_id = p.subscription_id
 where p.product_id = :something
```

Some points:

1. You have an alias `v` in your query; I don't know where this came from.
2. Learn to use the ANSI join syntax; if you make a mistake it's a lot more obvious.
3. You're selecting `a.acct_nbr`, which doesn't exist as-is.
4. There's no need for a DISTINCT. ACCOUNT_NBR and PRODUCT_ID are the primary key of ACCOUNT.

> Will the performance of the above query be low compared to two separate queries?

Probably not. If your query is correct and your tables are correctly indexed it's highly unlikely that whatever you've coded could beat the SQL engine. The database is designed to select data quickly.